# 栅 pronunciation - zhà vs. shān

Tags: pronunciation

As far as I know, the normal pronunciation of 栅 as in 栅栏 is zhà, but there is another pronunciation shān listed in dictionaries. Are both pronunciations in common use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronunciation shān is only really used in certain compound words:

- [光栅/光柵](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%85%89%E6%9F%B5), a *diffraction grating* used in optics.
- [栅极/柵極](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%A0%85%E6%9E%81), the *grid* of a vacuum tube or the *gate* of a transistor.

The [Taiwan](https://www.moedict.tw/%E5%85%89%E6%9F%B5) [standard](https://www.moedict.tw/%E6%9F%B5%E6%A5%B5) uses zhà for both even in this context.

Apparently, it also has another pronunciation, cè, for [certain placenames](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%A0%85) in Zhongshan, Guangdong.